# Pass Value between Java and C

Tags: java, c, variables

I have a Java GUI and a C program. C program calculates given value(args). I want to call C calculator in Java, and change label to returned value in GUI (label changes almost every second).

I thought some ways,

1. Socket programming (probably not efficient in same computer)
2. File operations (Java writes input, c calculates then java reads calculated value)
3. JNICALL stuff, but i dont know how to get value from c file.
4. SharedMemory (i have no idea about windows shm)

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Bit too broad of a question. You'd be better off trying one of your proposed solutions, and coming back with questions regarding actual code. One good way to do it (I forget how exactly to do it in java) is to create the process for the C program, and redirect `stdout` to capture its output.

Comment: Any particular motive on why you have two different programs?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen what you wrote is JNICALL stuff.

Comment: @Darth JNICALL is (I believe) for calling C *functions* from java, but from what you gave, it sounds like you want to run a C *program* (i.e. a separate process).

Comment: @vz0 C code is not mine, and i don't have time to implement it in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna), if your C program is a DLL with [export functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ys435b3s.aspx).

Remember from a past project it works very nicely, without having to do the JNI bits yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar at my job, I wrote a helper program in C++ to access some custom made database and my main application was in Java. The database API was only available to C++ programs.

What I did was to start the C++ process from Java and communicate via command line args and stdout.

```
    List<String> cmdPathAndArgs = Arrays.asList("/path/to/binary", "--arg1", "--arg2");
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdPathAndArgs);
    Processpp = pb.start();
    InputStream stream = pp.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

    InputStream errorStream = pp.getErrorStream();
    BufferedReader errorBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorStream));
```

If your progran generates output in both stdout and stderr you may get into a deadlock. You should empty both streams regularly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can build your C code into a shared library, then JNI is probably your best bet.  Sockets will be more than fast enough to handle 1 update a second.  Using files will probably be slower than sockets.  Shared memory is fine too, however I think sockets is probably a simpler interface for what you want to do.